Unable to ping jetson nano from other devices while connected via usb tethering
have a Dell PC (192.168.50.162) connected to a Wi-Fi network, along with my phone. My Jetson Nano (192.168.252.249) is connected to my phone (192.168.50.229) via USB tethering.
The issue I'm facing is that I can successfully ping my Dell PC from the Jetson Nano without any problem. However, I'm unable to ping the Jetson Nano from any other device connected to the same Wi-Fi network. This suggests that my phone might be blocking incoming messages to the Jetson Nano.
To troubleshoot, I've tried assigning a static IP address to the Jetson Nano within the same subnet as the network (192.168.50.x). However, when I do this, I lose internet connection on the Jetson Nano from my phone, including Wi-Fi connectivity.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can help me identify the issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Tethering means the phone acts as NAT gateway, therefore connections from Jetson Nano to other networks work, but reverse does not work. That is the same as your Wifi router allows you to connect to the internet but the internet devices can not scan devices in your local network. To bypass that you need connect the Jetson Nano using a Wifi bridge (a device that converts LAN to Wifi for exactly one device). On Android this can not be done unless your device is rooted. Then you might be able to set-up a port forwarding.
